# Why is the tree protocol deadlock free?

Tags: database, tree, locking, protocols, rdbms

I have been reading about the tree protocol as an approach in locking management in databases. I read that it is deadlock free but I am not sure how it works.
Example:
[image]

Assume that T1 has locked B, D, E in exclusive mode.
According to the rules:
[image]

T2 can lock H (allowed by rule 2).
Now if T1 wants to lock H it can not despite the fact that it has locked the parent D since T2 has the lock so it waits.
If T2 now wants to lock G it has to lock D but D is locked by T1 so it has to wait. Hence deadlock.
What am I misunderstanding in the algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, rule 2 of the tree protocol does not allow T2 to even request a lock on G, thus there cannot be a deadlock.

The first item locked by T2 is H. By rule 2, T2 can request locks only for descendants of H (J in the example).

If T2 needs a lock on both H and G, then the first lock request must be on their parent D (or any ancestor of both H and G).

Answer (score 0):

T2 cannot lock D as its parent is not locked by T2 at the time.

Comment: I am asking about lock on `H`. I assume it is a typo and you mean `H` and not `D`. In that case in the rule 2 there is no mention of the restriction you point out

Answer (score 0):

an explanation which i can think of is :

since locks can be released anytime, hence suppose T2 after accessing H in exclusive mode, releases it, hence T1 can access it 
and then suppose T1 releases all it locks and commits, after which T2 can acquire lock on A,B, D and then G

since it is not 2-phase locking hence locks can be released anytime.

If you have any other explanation, kindly share the same.

Comment: The steps happening as the ones described in OP.If you are interested in helping this is from the book of Silberschatz for RDBMs

Comment: the explanation is from Silberchatz yes. did it solve your doubt or still open for discussion??

Comment: My point was that in your answer you are describing a flow other than the one mentioned by Silberschatz. And to be honest I did not undestand what you mean. Where is the deadlock in your flow?

Comment: Reply if the following suffices(also if not):
do you want to understand how it is deadlock free, as thats what i tried to provide earlier----

Comment: T1 is waiting for T2 to release lock on H and T2 wants to lock G, hence waiting for T1 to release lock on D, this as you said leading to a deadlock. 
But since this algorithm is supposed to be deadlock free so i suggested that suppose in the interim T2 releases its lock on H (for whatever reasons) as locks can be released anytime, due to this event T1 can now acquire lock on H and can complete its work. Now T2 can in some time future see that it can lock G, as its parent is unlocked by T1, and can also lock H to finish its work it abandoned.

Comment: My explanation shows how to avoid a deadlock as i guess that was your question---
"If T2 now wants to lock G it has to lock D but D is locked by T1 so it has to wait. Hence deadlock. What am I misunderstanding in the algorithm?"

Comment: :The protocol is supposed to be deadlock free and I am asking why do I get a deadlock in this case. Not avoiding a deadlock

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is solved until now but I answer just for others.

In your scenario there is a problem and it is that T2 locked H for its first locking position (according to algorithm it's true and you can start from any position), but T2 never can climbing up to root and lock other nodes, so if T2 start from H never allowed to need G. For example if T2 needs G and H, so should start from a node that contain both.

let me know if my answer is true or wrong...

Comment: I still have not figured it out.Concerning your post. I am not sure what your answer is. The issue is that T2 is allowed to lock H and an attempt to lock G is a possible scenario. But in that case it ends in a deadlock. So the only way to avoid this would be if T2 trying to lock G is not a valid scenario. But this is not a requirement of the protocol which claims to be deadlock free. I mean there is no prerequisite that would make T2 not possible to ever try to access G

Comment: this scenario is not valid because if you read the protocol it is like this: each transaction start from arbitrary node, and can just lock child of that node !!! so the assumption that T2 lock H and need G is wrong !!! if T2 start from H so it never can claims to need G. after all it is obvious that this protocol is deadlock free. for your last sentence yeah there is no prerequisite for T2 but there are some rules (if T2 needs G, So it shouldn't start from H). the best way to find start node is the LCA of the nodes you need in your transaction (I suppose it is the best). is it solved?

Comment: So I assume you mean that the assumption is well-behaved transactions? Because otherwise I can't see why a sequence of H then G can not happen for T2

Comment: yeah, if T2 needs both G and H , it should start from some node that is ancestors of both G and H.